# Before vs Around advice precedence in @AspectJ-Style annotations

Tags: spring, aspectj

I have converted a simple Spring project made with pure aop namespace xml coding to the same project but using annotations this time.
I've noticed that now the before-part of the around advice comes out before the before advice, which is the exact opposite behavior of the project's result when I was using aop namespace xml coding.
Is it the default behavior of the annotation style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Advice ordering](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering):

> When two pieces of advice defined in different aspects both need to run at the same join point, unless you specify otherwise the order of execution is undefined. You can control the order of execution by specifying precedence. This is done in the normal Spring way by either implementing the org.springframework.core.Ordered interface in the aspect class or annotating it with the Order annotation. Given two aspects, the aspect returning the lower value from Ordered.getValue() (or the annotation value) has the higher precedence.

Since the ordering is undefined, it could possibly vary even between multiple executions (having the same xml config).

Comment: what's the order between before adice and the before part of around advice if the order of before is higher than around advice specified?